# update panel removes Jquery style

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

i am using the following JQuery UI code with asp.net controls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".Accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });

            $(".special").button();

            $(".radio").buttonset();

            //$(".tabs").tabs();
            $(".tabs").tabs();

        });

    </script>
```

and the code was working fine until i decided to put all of my controls in an update panel. On post back, all styles are removed from the controls.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should modify your script, because  $(document).ready() doesn't work with update panel:

```
function InitCss() {

        $(".Accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
        });

        $(".special").button();

        $(".radio").buttonset();

        //$(".tabs").tabs();
        $(".tabs").tabs();

    }

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitCss);
```

The same from code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("InitCss"))
        {
            string script = @"function InitCss() {

        $("".Accordion"").accordion({
            heightStyle: ""content""
        });

        $("".special"").button();

        $("".radio"").buttonset();

        //$("".tabs"").tabs();
        $("".tabs"").tabs();

    }

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitCss);";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "InitCss", script, true);
        }
}
```

Comment: **i have tried your code and still not working. it shows an error message "Error: 'Sys' is undefined" when the page first load**

Comment: Yes,this can occures if Sys object not presents on page until page not full loaded. You can take out your javascriptcode in outside js file

Comment: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() works only for partial postback. Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitCss) works partial and full postback. Its guarantee that your component will be initialized

Comment: thanks man..now it is working fine except for the Sys object still appear to me even when i placed the code in an external JS file..and that only happens on IE..FF and chrome are working well with no Sys error

Comment: i removed `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitCss);` from my code and now it is PERFECT..thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization will run only on document ready (not on postback). Since you place your control inside UpdatePanel, anything will updated after postback. You should call the initialization after postback too. Add this code to your beside your existing script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function(s, e) {
  $(".Accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });

            $(".special").button();

            $(".radio").buttonset();

            //$(".tabs").tabs();
            $(".tabs").tabs();
}); 
</scipt>
```